# Why does a sentence start with "For some people..........." where "Some people" is the subject of the sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, writing

**"For some people, no matter how much sleep they get, they still feel tired and low in energy. Why?"** [BBC-why some people always feel tired](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20240125-why-do-some-people-feel-tired-all-the-time)

**"Some people"** is the subject of the sentence. And when it is the subject, we simply use the subject without **"for"**. For example:

- **Some people** always feel tired. *(We don't start the sentence  **"For some people..."**)*
- **Some people** like tea.
- **Some people** consider money the most important thing in life.

So, similarly, the same is true for our sentence. It does not need to start with **"For"**. I mean we can simply say:

**"Some people, no matter how much sleep they get, still feel tired and low in energy."**

So, why does the sentence start with **"For some people...."** instead of **"Some people..."**?

Comment: **They** is the subject and **feel** the matrix verb; **for some people** is a prepositional phrase. I suspect people will have different opinions about the appropriateness of this structure and whether it's better to have *some people* as the subject, but grammatically it's quite simple. It's no different to something like "When it comes to Texans, they are more likely to ride horses".